# Disable AddThis notification tip on admin dashboard

Tags: notifications, wordpress

I have site network WordPress (Multisite) and the AddThis plugin activated. This problem is that in the blog a pop-over notification is displayed to the users. How can hide this?

The plugin has already been configured and logged in from the main site (superadmin). Other users should not see this notice in order to avoid confusion.

[image: addthis notice]

Comment: First, have you actually created a 'user' account to see if this message displays for them? This will always show up for the admin which is what you see.

Comment: Yes, I have created test users (Note that for each user created a blog for it is created). As mentioned before, the plugin has been configured by the superadmin, you need not configure each user. Will the plugin is not suitable for multisite?. @ham-sandwich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the following to [`wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) file:

```
define( 'ADDTHIS_NO_NOTICES', true );
```

Comment: Thanks! works :) I can't vote up your answer :( Vote Up requires 15 reputation @brasofilo